# For a given Heroku Dyno *instance*, is the external IP address stable for the lifetime of that instance?

Tags: heroku, ip-address

Can I count on the external IP address being stable for any given Dyno instance.

That is, my Dyno boots up and makes a request to some external service. That service notes the incoming IP address. Could that service assume that any subsequent traffic *from that same Dyno instance* would come from the same IP address. Will the same apply if the same Dyno makes a request to a very different endpoint?

I understand that Heroku makes no guarantees about Dyno addressing unless you upgrade to the Private level offering (or otherwise spend more on addons or Enterprise features). I'm not looking to know in advance which IPs to expect, just whether it's stable.

I assume the architecture is fairly obvious: containers running on VMs that have outbound network access using the VM's interface, so external IPs for outbound connections are going to be the VM IP address. However, Heroku emphasizes it's Routing layer and makes it sound complicated, so you never know if they have some kind of outbound routing complexity as well, which is what I'm worried about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a broad level, you should never expect IP addresses to be stable on Heroku *by default*. This applies to DNS targets, hence the requirements for CNAMEs everywhere, and outbound IPs.

Regarding the specific question, yes, a single *specific Dyno instance* will have the same outbound IP address, but that means it will only be stable for ~24 hours (+3 1/2 hours possibly, see [/Dynos#restarting](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting)) at most. After `web.1`'s daily cycle, the newly launched `web.1` will have a new public IP address. `web.1`, `web.2`, `web.3`, `web.#`…, along with any/all other process groups' Dynos will likely never have the same public IP address at the same time.

There are means for stabilizing outbound IPs longer term, as is accomplished by various [Proxy partner add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/categories/network), or any other Proxy service you choose to use.

Comment: I just heard back from someone at Heroku and they confirmed this as well. Thanks!